# Conditional version of Bayes formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm doing a course on Advanced Probability and struggle hard with the topic of conditional expectations. There is one exercise in the Book of Klenke, which makes me wonder:
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{F}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{A}$. Prove the conditional version of Bayes' formula: for $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and $F\in \mathcal{F}$: $$\mathbb{P(F|\mathcal{A})}= \frac{\int_F\mathbb{P}(A|\mathcal{F})d\mathbb{P}}{\int_\Omega\mathbb{P}(A|\mathcal{F})d\mathbb{P}}.$$ How can one prove that? As far as I know it holds $\mathbb{P}(A|\mathcal{F})=\mathbb{E}(1_{A}|\mathcal{F})$, so I would put that in. But then I have no clue of where to go. Are there some probability experts? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, it looks like there are multiple typos. (E.g. why would you condition on the entire $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$? The conditional probability of an event given the entire $\sigma$-algebra is just the indicator function of the event. And what is $\mathbb{F}$?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to show if $A\in\mathcal A, B\in \mathcal F$ where $ \mathcal F\subset \mathcal A$ is a sub sigma algebra then,

> $\mathbb P(B\mid A)=\frac{\int _B \mathbb P(A\mid \mathcal F)d\mathbb P}{\int \mathbb P(A\mid \mathcal F)d\mathbb P}$.

Suppose $\mathbb P(A)>0$. Now $$\frac{\int _B \mathbb P(A\mid \mathcal F)d\mathbb P}{\int \mathbb P(A\mid \mathcal F)d\mathbb P}=\frac{\int_B E(1_A\mid \mathcal F)d\mathbb P}{\int E(1_A\mid \mathcal F)d\mathbb P}=\frac{\int E(1_{A\cap B}\mid \mathcal F)d\mathbb P}{E(1_A)}=\frac{E(E(1_{A\cap B}\mid \mathcal F))}{\mathbb P(A)}=\frac{E(1_{A\cap B})}{\mathbb P(A)}=P(B\mid A).$$ We use the definition of the conditional probability in the first step, second step is since $B\in\mathcal F$, i.e $1_B$ is measurable with resepct to $\mathcal F$, further we use in the second and third the definition of a conditional expectation.

Hope that will help you.